# Javascript map to array, get and set

Tags: javascript, dictionary, get, set

```
let myMap = new Map();

myMap.set(1, [1,2,3]);
myMap.set(1, myMap.get(1).push(4));

console.log(myMap);
```

In the above code, 1 is mapped to the array [1,2,3]. Then I want to add 4 to this array. However when I do a console.log, myMap turns out to be just 4 and not the array [1, 2, 3, 4]

Why?

But if I do

```
olds = myMap.get(1);
olds.push(4)
```

then things work as expected.

Comment: You don't need to `set` a new value, you're mutating the old one. Just `myMap.get(1).push(4)`

Answer (score 0):

It's because `push` returns the new length of the array which happens to be 4 in this case and you are setting it to be the new value. You are basically doing this:

```
// ...
const new_length = myMap.get(1).push(4);
myMap.set(1, new_length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your instruction `myMap.set(1, myMap.get(1).push(4));` actually translates to `myMap.set(1, 4)` as the length of the array is returned on the `push` method.

I think what you want to do is `myMap.get(1).push(4)` which will assign `[1, 2, 3, 4]` to `1` in `myMap`. (but still return the length of the array)